# What is the difference between python and ipython console?

Tags: python

I am new to python. I am using spyder editor. I did basic print out the values of total and average. But, When i ran this code on python console, i got the error "num1 is not defined". However, when i ran this code on i-python console, it worked perfectly. I am asking why do I get error on python console.

```
def problem1(num1,num2,num3):
    total = num1+num2+num3
    average = total/3
    print("The sum of numbers are: ",total)
    print("The average of numbers are:  ",average)
    return(total,average)

num1 = eval(input("Enter the number 1: "))
num2 = eval(input("Enter the number 2: "))
num3 = eval(input("Enter the number 3: "))

problem1(num1,num2,num3)
```

Comment: Please provide full error message, as this could have happened in several places.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1
    num2 = eval(input("Enter the number 2: "))
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> num3 = eval(input("Enter the number 3: "))
Enter the number 3: problem1(num1,num2,num3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'num1' is not defined

Comment: Also, please remove `eval` calls, they don't make any sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you paste this code to Python console, the line `num2 = eval(input("Enter the number 2: "))` is eval'ed as the answer to the first `input` and you get a SyntaxError there:

```
>>> num1 = eval(input("Enter the number 1: "))
Enter the number 1: num2 = eval(input("Enter the number 2: "))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1
    num2 = eval(input("Enter the number 2: "))
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The problem is that when you're pasting code to the Python console, it doesn't stop at `input`, it just feeds whatever you're pasting as the answer to the input.

But also, as a side note: [`eval` is dangerous](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html). If you just need to cast a string to a number, you can use `int(...)` or `float(...)`.